# While working on Ruby on Rails I came across this. Can someone explain this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, data-structures, key-value

I came across this little piece of code from Ruby on Rails. Can some one please take time in explaining this -   `all_account_id = Rails.configuration.lsr_api_account_id[:prod] + account_id.split(",").map(&:strip)` Especially the last piece `.split(",").map(&:strip)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code is simply concatenating 2 different strings.

if the string looks like this `"ab, cd, ef"` then the split method will return an array and the elements in that array will be from the string separated by
a comma. e.g.
`"a, b, c".split(",")` will return `["a", " b", " c"]`
You can see further examples from https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split

.map is like a loop, it'll be run on each element of the array that's returned by split, there's a method inside map, that's strip, as name suggest it removes extra spaces (if any) from the string

e.g. if split return something like `[" a ", "b ", "    c"]` then `map(&:strip)` will remove extra spaces from each element.

Note: Remeber, map and split are 2 different things, you can explore them using below links
https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map
https://apidock.com/ruby/String/strip

Comment: `map(&:strip)` is a shorthand way of writing `map{|string| string.strip}`